# Raspi-config issue -- SPI & I2C

Tags: raspi-config

SBC:    Raspberry Pi 3B
OS:     Ubuntu 18.04

Enabling SPI causes raspi-config to respond with ``Programmer error: unrecognized option''.
Enabling I2C causes raspi-config to enable SPI.

Enabling I2C in /boot/config.txt works.

The question now is, how am I supposed to enable SPI? (Joe's edit)

/Farad'n

```
HummingBoard I2EX   Raspberry Pi 3B
Odroid XU4          RockPro64
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I don't think raspi-config is supported on any OS other than Raspbian. Also what's your question?